# Fill a textview from other activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a timetable and to do that I created two activities with two java codes 
Here is the beggining of the xml part of the first activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.clmentine.emploidutemps.MainActivity">


<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/textView66"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/lundi"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:maxWidth="60dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b829d8"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/mardi"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:maxWidth="60dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b829d8"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/mercredi"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:maxWidth="60dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b829d8"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/jeudi"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:maxWidth="60dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b829d8"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/vendredi"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:maxWidth="60dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b829d8"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="50dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/un"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:maxWidth="50dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="55dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/Lundi1"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/Mardi1"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/Mercredi1"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/Jeudi1"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
            android:minWidth="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/Vendredi1"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/plus"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:maxWidth="50dp"
    android:textColor="#060606"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:background="#b326ef"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/retour"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:textColor="#060606"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:maxHeight="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:background="#b326ef"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="75dp" />
```

Then the java code I was able to create a button to link the activities

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
public TextView textViewObj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textViewObj=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent appel = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BisActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(appel , 1) ;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
        textViewObj.setText(data.getStringExtra("text")) ;
    }
}

}
```

Then in my second activity I tried

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class BisActivity extends Activity {

Button boutonvalider;
EditText editText ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bis);

    boutonvalider=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boutonvalider);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    boutonvalider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String textViewString = editText.getText().toString() ;
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("text", textViewString);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        }

    });
}
}
```

I could like to be to write something in an edittext in my second activity instead of adding an "a" add what I wrote

Please help me

This is the xml code of my second activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.clmentine.emploidutemps.BisActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matiere"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/matiere"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rentrermatiere"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/matiere"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="150dp" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/valider"
    android:id="@+id/boutonvalider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/heureetdate"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rentrermatiere"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#070707" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first activity you can use:

```
Intent appel = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BisActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(appel , REQUEST_CODE);
```

instead of `startActivity();`

and override `onActivityResult` method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    String requestedString= intent.getStringExtra("text");
}
```

and on the second activity use:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("text", result stirng);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to take the data from a EditText in the second activity and put them in a specific TextView in the first activity.

Instead of startActivity, use startActivityForResult, like this:

```
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent appel = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BisActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(appel , 1) ;
```

now, use onActivityResult to retrieve the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
        tv.setText(data.getStringExtra("text")) ;
    }  
}
```

In your first activity you should have something like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    public TextView textViewObj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       textViewObj=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               Intent appel = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BisActivity.class);
               startActivityForResult(appel , 1) ;
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
            textViewObj.setText(data.getStringExtra("text")) ;
        }  
    }

}
```

and in your second activity (BisActivity), if you want your button to update the first activity textView and go back to the first activity at once, do this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BisActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bis);

        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boutonvalider);
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String textViewString = editText.getText().toString() ;
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.putExtra("text", textViewString);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything I am new on android studio what is it supposed to do ?

Comment: And how do I chose in the xml code the textview I want to fill ?

Comment: declaring your textview as a static value isn't a good approach.
instead, you should send back your string from the second activity(with intent.putExtra) and make the first activity updated with data recieved from the second activity(with onActivityResult).

Comment: I did exactly as you said for my java code but how do I chose which textview I want to fill ?

Comment: I just editted my first post to show you exactly how is my code

Comment: Please help me it's for an exam I have to present it tommorrow

Comment: :app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027layout_behavior\u0027 in package \u0027com.example.clmentine.emploidutemps\u0027","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Programmeandroid\\Emploidutemps\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_bis.xml","position":

Comment: {"startLine":1}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027layout_behavior\u0027 with value \u0027@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Programmeandroid\\Emploidutemps\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_bis.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":25,"startOffset":575,"endColumn":63,"endOffset":613}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Programmeandroid\Android\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED